# How do you overlay text on images/videos?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, flowplayer

We need to place text over objects in a web page, similar to this: http://www.queness.com/resources/html/slideshow/jquery-slideshow.html

The text "bar" needs to appear on top of images and videos. For the videos, we're using the html5media library (http://code.google.com/p/html5media/), which renders a `<video>` tag for those browsers that support it, or a Flowplayer for others.

How do you do this with jQuery? Is it even possible for videos? There are examples but none that allow for text to be on top of `<video>` or Flowplayer objects. Thanks.

Comment: For flowplayer you should set `wmode` to `transparent` or `opaque`

Comment: Thanks. It's a little more complicated: I'm also using the jQuery Background Canvas library, which puts a canvas object into the mix. With `wmode` set to `transparent`, IE6 lets you see through the video player into the canvas -- it's like there's a veil on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have your flash object in wmode=opaque in order to be able to place html on top of it

Comment: Thanks, XGreen and dev-null-dweller. That works in all browsers except IE6 (and lower) -- and I know why: It's the CANVAS object from the jQuery Background Canvas library, used to create transparency and rounded corners for the container DIV. 

On IE6, you get a cloudy video, because the CANVAS is either on top or somehow interfering with the opaque video.

Comment: By the way, for those interested in adding the opaque parameter to Flowplayer, you need to add it to the following variable in the Flowplayer JavaScript library file: var i={width:"100%",height:"100%",allowfullscreen:true,wmode:"opaque",
allowscriptaccess:"always",quality:"high",version:null,onFail:null,
expressInstall:null,w3c:false,cachebusting:false}

Comment: I really think we as programmers should start to incorporate the following code in our pages:

if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0") alert("Sorry if you haven't updated yet you better forget about the web");

:)

Comment: Oh, I wish so much that we could do that, XGreen! IE6 makes everything so much harder. In a few years, when its usage drops to where IE 5.x is, we can abandon it. Some companies (Google and YouTube) have already stopped supporting it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried absolute positioning for text, with a transparent background?

Comment: Yes, but the text goes underneath.

Comment: did you set the z-index css property to put them on top?